# Are convenience functions a good practice?

Tags: c++, oop

I am writing a C++ project and am thinking about coding some functions that always have the same parameters and the same output, moreover different (and unrelated) classes will use them. But I am now reluctant as I have the feeling that such "convenience" functions are not as OOP as it should be and I am ought to code a minimal class for those functions. So, from a C++ point of view, are convenience functions a good OOP programming practice? Is this a sign of a bad design?

An example for illustration:

Let's say we have two classes, `class Sphere` and `class Pillow`. Bot have a member variable `char[8] hash` for some (maybe different) hashing reasons but always using the same hash algorithm. Now I have three options:

- implement a member function `makeHash()` for each class
- implement a convenience function `makeHash()` that gets called by the classes
- refactor the complete design to make `Sphere`and `Pillow` child classes of the same parent class

I don't like the first as it creates duplicate code and I don't like the last option because it leads to "cluster of classes" where every class is more or less a relative of another class (which is clearly bad OOP).

Of course, OOP is more of an art (and sometimes religion) than an exact science. However **is it in general a good practice to create convenience functions when designing in OOP**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you were sticking to OOP design, then your `char[8] hash` would be an actual `Hash` class. Then this solves your problem.

Comment: +1 a nice side-effect of using a `Hash` class is that it makes the type system more useful (i.e. more power to the compiler!).

Comment: This is what I was thinking but wouldn't that create quite an overhead? After all, I would then have to allocate space for a whole class (that basically holds that `char[8]`) and not _just_ the `char`.

Comment: @alex If that class does not have multiple parents and has no virtual functions, its memory footprint will be identical to that of its members, hence no overhead.

Answer (score 3):

It is always good practice to factor common code into separate modules since it reduces code duplication and gives you a change to assign a descriptive name to a piece of code.

In order to keep your code modular (i.e. reduce the 'ripple effect' when changing something), it makes perfect sense to look for a concept to model a piece of code with the minimum amount of dependencies.

A global function which only depends on its arguments and has no side effects (i.e. the only result is returned in the return value) makes perfect sense for that reason.